# What is the difference between Gradient Boosting Machines and Gradient Boosted Regression Trees?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, cart, ensemble-learning

I would like to know if Gradient Boosting Machines and Gradient Boosted Regression Trees are the same algorithm or different. If they are different algorithms what is the main difference between them?

Comment: This question will be very difficult to answer without specific examples of both claims.

Comment: Agreed, please supply references.

Comment: I just want to know what is the main difference between this two algorithms, I mean between  Gradient Boosting Machines and Gradient Boosted Regression Trees.